# GWT History Problem

Tags: url, gwt, history, gwt-history

when i am adding a new history item like this

History.newItem("Register");

the url correcly changes to

http://127.0.0.1:8888/BiddingSystem.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#Register

and loads the register form

but then the url automatically rechanges to

http://127.0.0.1:8888/BiddingSystem.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#

why??

because I want to remain as

http://127.0.0.1:8888/BiddingSystem.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#Register

so that user can reload

Comment: Ya, now i understand the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that I was using an hyperlink for acting like a click handler. with a hyperlink, event if u place an empty string, it gonna change the url.

e.g. if the current URL is something like `http:...//#This` and a hyperlink has an empty target history token then, the url is to change to `http:...//#.`

The solution i used that worked for me is that because i does not want to use a button, i make use of label and adding some css to it to make it look like a hyperlink

for e.g.

```
Label Register= new Label("register");
Label.setStyleName("FalseHyperlink");
```

then in the css

```
.FalseHyperlink
{
   color:blue;
}

.FalseHyperlink:hover
{
   text-decortion:underline;
}
```

Here this solution worked for me because i was not interested in other hyperlink services such as visited or others

Comment: The simpler solution would be to use `event.preventDefault()` in click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Check if any empty string added to History after page rendered or correct history token added to history? URL is changed when a string added to History.